# Could not create semaphore set: No space left on device Perl

Tags: perl, parallel-processing, ipc, shared-memory

I am trying to use shared memory in Perl. It seems to work well, but I have noticed that I am getting the following error after some program starts:

```
Could not create semaphore set: No space left on device
```

Here is my declaration of shared variables:

```
my $handle_buffer = tie $buffer, 'IPC::Shareable', undef, { destroy => 1 };
my $clients_shr = tie @clients, 'IPC::Shareable', undef, { destroy => 1 };
```

I have tried to clear all variables using the following subroutine:

```
 IPC::Shareable->clean_up_all;
 ..... killing child process
```

But it doesn't work. It seems to hang, because after that not all processes are killed and continue reading from shared memory and getting:

```
Use of uninitialized value $shared_variable in string eq at shared.pl line 208, <GEN1> line 14.**
```

Please help to release memory. Thanks everyone in advance.

**EDIT**

Here is simple example

```
use IPC::Shareable;
my $buffer;
my $handle_buffer = tie $buffer, 'IPC::Shareable', undef, { destroy => 1 };
$buffer = "Initial value\n";
setpgrp(0,0);
$SIG{INT} = \&kill_all;
sub kill_all() {
     print "Going to kill child processes \n";
     print "Clearing shared memory \n";
     IPC::Shareable->clean_up_all;
     kill -$$;
}
if( fork() == 0 ){
$SIG{INT} = 'DEFAULT';   
    $buffer = "Some value from child";
}
.....
.....
if(fork() == 0) {
$SIG{INT} = 'DEFAULT';   
   if($buffer==$some_value) {

}
}
```

Comment: Could you perhaps post a [minimal example demonstrating the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? That might help others reproduce and diagnose it.

Comment: And that code runs and demonstrates the problem, if you comment out the "....." part?